# usar Split en Python

Tags: python

en mi programa, mi Raspberry recibe una llamada por un módulo GSM y por el serial recibo

```
RING



+CLIP: "633555999",161,"",0,"",0
```

cada vez que da un tono (me he inventado el número).
Lo que necesito es que de toda esta string que me manda, separar la palabra RING para detectar cuando me llaman y a continuación separar el número de teléfono para posteriormente enviarle un SMS.
Os dejo mi programa:

```
import serial
import time
from curses import ascii
sSerie = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)
while True:
    try:
        llamando1 = sSerie.readline()
        a,b= llamando1.split("+")
        print a
        if a == "RING":
            num = sSerie.readline()
            morralla, numero, morralla2 = num.split('"',2)
            sSerie.write('ATH\r\n')
            print 'numero que te ha llamado =' + str(numero)


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
                quit()
```

Con este programa no consigo que compare bien la variable a con el RING y me sale esto:

```
File "testllamada.py", line 8, in <module>
    a,b = llamando1.split(" ")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Si solo pongo `a` en lugar de `a,b` si que me lo separa pero con el `print a` me sale algo parecido a esto:

```
[\n\r]
[RING\n\r]
[\n\r]
[( ,) CLIP: "633555999",161,"",0,"",0\n\r]
```

Y no se como coger solo la segunda línea.
Si alguien me puede ayudar le estaré muy agradecido.

Comment: Es muy raro lo que te ocurre, la línea mencionada en el mensaje de error `a,b = llamando1.split(" ")` no aparece en el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que entendí, lees lineas desde un puerto y las procesas secuencialmente, si aparece una línea `RING` debes esperar en algún momento una línea `CLIP:`. Para simular este comportamiento prepare una lista de líneas a recibir y hago una iteración sobre las mismas en el orden de llegada

```
lineas = ["", "RING", "", "", "","+CLIP: ""633555999"",161,"""",0,"""",0"]

estado = -1
for l in lineas:

  if l == "RING":
    estado == 1 # Llamada

  if estado == 1:
    if l[:5] == "+CLIP":
      numero = l[7:].split(",")[0]
      print 'numero que te ha llamado =' + numero
      estado = -1
```

Lo que se hace es:

1. Al recibir un `RING` establecemos un estado `estado = 1` que representa que actualmente estamos procesando una llamada, esto para diferenciar lógicas frente a otras eventuales operaciones. Lo concreto es que el sistema quedará a la espera de un `+CLIP` para finalizar la lógica
2. Si la siguiente línea tiene el texto `+CLIP:` (usamos un "string slice" mediante `l[:5]`) simplemente recortamos la línea por el texto posterior a `+CLIP:` y hacemos un `split()` con la coma como separador, lo que nos devolvería algo así: `['633555999', '161', '', '0', '', '0']`, por lo que usando el índice obtenemos fácilmente el dato que estamos buscando
3. Por último, volvemos el estado a -1 para reiniciar el ciclo, y el sistema quedaría esperando la siguiente "operación".

Esta es una forma bien básica de resolver el problema, adaptándolo a tu código, sería algo así:

```
import serial
import time
from curses import ascii

sSerie = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)
estado = -1
while True:
    try:
        l = sSerie.readline()

        if a == "RING":
           estado = 1 # Llamada

        if estado == 1:
           if l[:5] == "+CLIP":
             numero = l[7:].split(",")[0]
             sSerie.write('ATH\r\n')
             print 'numero que te ha llamado =' + numero
             estado = -1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
                quit()
```

Si como mencionas en tu último comentario no recibes línea a línea sino el texto completo, es mucho más sencillo hacer lo siguiente:

```
txt ="""RING



+CLIP: "633555999",161,"",0,"",0"""

lista = txt.split()

if len(lista) >= 3 and lista[0] == "RING":
  numero = lista[2].split(",")[0].replace('"','')
  print("Numero: {}".format(numero))
```

En primer lugar nos quedamos con cada uno de los textos usando como separador los espacios o caracteres de fin de línea(`lista = txt.split()`), 
esto nos devuelve una lista como la siguiente:

```
['RING', '+CLIP:', '"633555999",161,"",0,"",0']
```

Así ya tenemos más claro como recuperar el número, pero como no sabemos si siempre recibiremos este único texto conviene ser precavidos y verificar que al menos obtuvimos tres cadenas, y que la primera de ellas que la primera sea "RING", si es así el número será la tercer cadena de la lista, y sobre esta volvemos a aplicar el `split()` esta vez separando`,`, el primer valor es el número.

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Al usar `for l in lineas == "RING"` estas comparando a cada palabra con RING ? En el puerto no entra nada hasta que llaman, y cuando llaman recibe el RING y la linea `+CLIP: "633555999",161,"",0,"",0` todo seguido.

Comment: Efectivamente, por como estaba tu ejemplo pensé que recibías lineas del puerto, si recibes el comando completo, todo se simplifica. Agregué un procesamiento por medio de split() a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> serial.Serial.read_all.__doc__
'        Read all bytes currently available in the buffer of the OS.\n        '
```

En vez de usar readline podrías leer todo de golpe, comprobar si "RING" está en el string que te devuelve y luego buscar el número usando split o expresiones regulares. Lo de las expresiones regulares tiene la ventaja de que si desde la última lectura has recibido más de una llamada puedes obtener fácilmente todos los números de golpe. Aunque creo que no es muy plausible que ocurra.

```
>>> data
'RING\n\n\n\n+CLIP: "633555999",161,"",0,"",0RING\n\n\n\n+CLIP: "633555888",161,"",0,"",0RING\n\n\n\n+CLIP: "633555777",161,"",0,"",0'
>>> pattern = re.compile("""RING.*?CLIP: "(\d*)""", re.DOTALL)
>>> re.findall(pattern, data)
['633555999', '633555888', '633555777']
```

NOTA: Es posible que si no usas el método flushOutput cada vez que llames al método read_all te retorne siempre el texto anterior + el nuevo, no estoy seguro, haz pruebas porque no se si al llamar a read_all el buffer se limpia o no.

Comment: No necesito guardar nada, es un localizador que recibe una llamada, cuelga y envia un sms al número que le ha llamado con las coordenadas del localizador. Lo único que necesito es que saber que me estan llamando leyendo el RING o de cualquier otra forma y a continuación aislar el número.